# Async flow having different execution times

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have the two APIs, which call the same services.

This version performs in the time that the at most expensive task takes.

```
public async Task<double> Do()
{
    var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var t1 = _service.Do1();
    var t2 = _service.Do2();

    await t1;
    await t2;

    return sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

While this one performs in sum of each task delay.

```
public async Task<double> Do()
{
   var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

   await _service.Do1();
   await _service.Do2();

   return sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
}

internal async Task Do1() => await Task.Delay(5000);
internal async Task Do2() => await Task.Delay(2000);
```

Why is that, what is actually happening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tasks return "hot", or already started. The `await` keyword quite literally means hold here and wait for the task to complete. As such, when you await each operation individually, it's calling `Do1`, waiting for that to finish, and then calling `Do2` and waiting for that to finish.

However, when you just store them in variables, it calls `Do1`, and then it calls `Do2`, while `Do1` is still running. Later when you `await` these two variables, the code will hold waiting for each to actually complete on by one, but they're already both running.

Long and short, it's the difference between running serially and in parallel. Asynchronous operations *can* be run parallel, but they are not parallel by nature: it's two different concepts.

Answer (score 2):

```
var t1 = _service.Do1(); < --- your 1st task started
var t2 = _service.Do2(); < --- your 2nd task started

await t1; < --- 1st awaited but it already did at least part of its job so far
await t2; < --- 2nd task awaited but, if its light task, probably already done so nothing to await
```

vs

```
   await _service.Do1(); < --- 1st task started and blocks 2nd from starting
   await _service.Do2(); < --- 2nd starts only after 1st finished
```

Obviously, case 1 runs in parallel for some time while second one runs in series thus takes full time of both tasks summed.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case both tasks will be started before you await one of them. So you need only the time `max(time(task1), time(task2))`.

In the second case you start the first task wait for it to finish and then start the second one, so your time will be `time(task1) + time(task2)`

**Edit:**
Also be aware of CPU-bound Tasks as Tasks will not automatically run parallel if executed on the same thread, e.g.

```
public static async Task<double> Do()
{
    var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var t1 = Do1();
    var t2 = Do2();

    await t1;
    await t2;

    var time = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine("time="+time); // time=3002.3204
    return time;
}

public static async Task Do1()
{
    var t = Task.Delay(1000);

    while(t.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {}

    await t;
}

public static async Task Do2()
{
    var t = Task.Delay(2000);

    while(t.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {}

    await t;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVLLTsMwEDzXX2E4OUJYba6lSKhFXAChthIHxGFJVq2FY0feDVFV9duLnZRHkRAXcnFm4tmZ3WxB54UPuG/IuJVcbIixGovvSC/XAaGMhF4CvdJYCAcVUg0FyjswTm5F3bxYU8jCApF8CH4VoJLb/YEmBo4H0MYVMtW4KH38gpdy5lUmtkLGZ/AGQVIrJx@2MwMr5ykqSS/Y1y1wsY5vEPgeW5XFHJ86HkXdzI8S@0XmHZknctDT0ILheHt8BPOjUqbCqKNWX1uoCUu99Az2zlhrCAvvyjiBwdQ78hb1YzCMt8ahOk3CyelZOpJhQG6C68qNxU6I32bRx45D6N2jdWL1DC1s1Gg4HHbpB@3aWFSc@ueG5El/rUd6Dm7pp76qLbLxLpPbXdIc2vvLPv/VPv8n@x@L8OZN2W2OIg5xr56eJYQVdSk693njVB9RZXJyKftKaVkyfYN8lSAG1YE5UmM5/ePY5W63fwc)